# Twitter Bootstrap - How to customize padding

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, customization

I just have a simple question regarding the cutomization form for Twitter Bootstrap: When I change the fields for container padding and download the customized bootstrap, the padding I set i.e., 20px doesn't end up in the css. Am I missing something?

Thanks,

J

Comment: Can you please mention which LESS variable's value have you customised..

Comment: I changed all of the padding fields on the customize form: padding-base-vertical, padding-base-horizontal, padding-large-vertical, padding-large-horizontal, etc.

Answer (score 2):

```
/* Minimize the default padding of the bootstrap container */
.container-fluid {
    padding: 4px;
}
```

Include this in your `CSS` and enjoy, similarly you can customize other `less variables` too.

Comment: does this mean that you have to stick to fluid columns also?

Comment: @JoeIsaacson I couldn't get you. Do you mean to ask, whether its applicable to container class also?
If this is your question then the answer is yes, you can customize your container class also, if you are not using container-fluid class.